# Javascript - regex replace string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to replace a string using regex but I must doing something wrong.

I would like to replace all text/string between `<!--StartFragment-->` to `<!--EndFragment-->`

```
<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:36.0pt'>
<!--StartFragment--><span style='font-size:11.0pt;line-height:107%;
font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;mso-fareast-font-family:
Calibri;mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
mso-bidi-font-family:Arial;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;mso-ansi-language:
EN-US;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:HE'>Hello how are you?</span><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
```

I tried to use something like:

```
content = content.replace(/<!--StartFragment-->(.+?)<!--EndFragment-->/, '<i>new replaced string</i>');
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's just a comment in html. It's not being even parsed.

Comment: [`<!--StartFragment-->[\s\S]*?<!--EndFragment-->`](https://regex101.com/r/HLw5Uz/1)?

Comment: @Kinduser OP wants to remove content **between** those two.

Comment: @Kinduser It's being parsed it just not getting viewed by the user. Or how else could JS know it's a comment?

Comment: [`.` (The dot, the decimal point) matches any single character except line terminators: \n, \r, \u2028 or \u2029.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir *JS know* - didn't you mean html?

Comment: @Kinduser Yeah JS, HTML, CSS they all go through that parsing phase.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Anyways 'code' provided doesn't make any sense, thanks to Wiktor for closing it.